# Replace "link" with "description" in mini-Markdown example

Tags: feature-request, comments, editing-help

I'm using Stack Overflow for months now but I must admit, I still can't remember the mini-formatting style for the links. When I click *help* link during writing comments, I can *theoretically* find proper syntax:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  `[link](http://example.com)`

But for me personally, this description is very misleading. I always do not know how I should interpret this `link` word. Should I put `[google link](http://google.com)` or `[http://google.com](google link)`. I do not feel silly but I've made such mistakes quite many times. So my proposition is - can we just change this help description to:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:  `[description](http://example.com)`

This is small change but I believe, for sure, will not lead to any mistakes any more.

Comment: +1. If anyone's seen a comment from me before which had a link in it, chances are you've seen me do it wrong.

Comment: Maybe "[link text]"?

Comment: Maybe I'm not the best person to provide feedback on this, considering I use `[description](URL)` format links everywhere, even in actual posts... :p

Comment: How about "[text to display]"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because belongs on MSE.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: It's on topic on either site.

Comment: Agree, *link* may be misunderstood, but how is *http://example.com* misleading? I mean, if you have to put an URL in parentheses, then the description necessarily goes into the square bracket.

Comment: @nico: the simple placeholder phrase [`enter code here`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22enter%20code%20here%22) is enough to confuse some posters...

Comment: I always thought the [link] was a literal. Didn't realise link is a placeholder for the anchor text.

Comment: Every single time I need that help it takes me a moment to parse that it's the *title* and not the *link* that goes there. And still, after almost three years this small but important change hasn't been implemented? Silly...

Answer (score 25):

I agree: `link` is quite misleading.

However, `description` doesn't really make sense: the proper term for this is [anchor text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_text).

So, it would be

```
[anchor text](http://example.com)
```

---

It seems that a lot of people don't know what anchor text is, and, as a website where many people don't speak English natively, it's probably a better idea to go with something simpler.

The most popular appears to be `[link description](http://example.com)` (or `(link)`).

Comment: I didn't even know what "anchor text" was until now. Sorry, but I think this might be a bit confusing, too, as quite a few people probably don't know what anchor text is.

Comment: @hichris123 Maybe; it's just something that stuck in the back of my head. Would `text` be better?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. Maybe I'm the only one who doesn't know what anchor text is. ;P

Comment: @hichris123 No one mentioned it in the comments above, so you can't be the only one...

Comment: Whether or not I knew what "anchor text" was, I'd probably guess based on the "text" part that it's the text-that-shows-up-and-you-click-on-it bit (or you could google "anchor text"). This and [text to display] as suggested by bheklilr are the best options, IMO.

Comment: What about `[link description](http://example.com)` ? I think this states the obvious and everybody will get what it means, unlike "anchor text". Since this site is used by people from many languages the simpler is the better.

Comment: @hichris123 If you're a professional or enthusiast programmer though, you'll be able to find out what anchor text means.  :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I think that's [where our problems begin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262446/are-we-being-elitist-is-there-something-wrong-with-that/262522)...

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor The point here is not to teach people what "anchor text" means but to help them understand how the bbcode is formatted. When you want to enter a link in a comment you don't want to search for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth if you use the editor UI to add a link (note that "optional title" is the link's `title` attribute, not the link text):

[image]

It will be inserted with the following placeholder text<sup>1</sup> (highlighted so you can type over it immediately, title left out because being optional almost nobody ever fills that in):

```
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://example.com
```

This has been the case basically forever. I think "link description" is fine to use.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Naturally, some users absentmindedly leave this in, triggering a flurry of NAA/VLQ flags and making deleting answers very trivial.</sub>

Comment: Doesn't... Doesn't this only work in questions/answers, not comments?

Comment: @Dannnno: Yes, but the link description syntax remains the same. I'm referring to the fact that the editor UI calls this a link description.