# Was I wrong in a mini-rant?

Tags: discussion

A user [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208284/homemade-captcha-system-one-minor-glitch-in-javascript-cant-enable-submit/25208351) and then provided a fiddle for the code in question.

The actual issue turned out to be extremely minor, so I

- Forked the fiddle and provided updated code that solved his issue
- Explained how basic debugging would have solved his issue for him with the use of some `console.log` statements.

I realize that SOI is a Q&A site and not a 'teach me to code' site so my question is:

Should my mini-rant, AKA debugging explanation be edited out?

Comment: Hey Jeremy, what makes you question your actions? I took a brief look at your answer and I'm not sure I see a problem.

Comment: @jmort253 Two things.  a) I felt really snarky when I did it, though I tried to keep my wording professional.  b) It felt a lot like "teaching to code."  Part of me felt like I should just answer the question of whats wrong with the code and leave it at that.

Comment: You were helpful. You obviously have concern for remaining polite and professional. You want feedback to know if what you did was ok. You are officially my favorite Stack Overflow user of the day.

Comment: Well, there goes my goal for today @AndrewBarber. I'll go back to bed then.

Comment: "Useful to other people" does not imply "useless to the asker."  You did fine.

Comment: @Bart You were snarky. You have goals. You give up on them far you easily. You are unofficially my favorite Bart of the day.

Comment: The fact that you question your post shows you feel there's an issue here. What I love about electronic communications, be it email or messages/comments on StackExchange or whatever, is that I can go back and edit out the portions of my communications that post-posting I will really wish I'd edited out. (Don't ask me how I know... :-) Sometimes when I see a question like this I'll *write* the "snarky" answer - then I'll take a deep breath, get out my trusty `backspace` and `delete` keys, and edit it into something that conveys the same information without treating someone badly. Best of luck.

Comment: I find these kind of answers useful, because I didn't know that online compilers and debuggers existed for so many progamming languages. When I find a question that I can answer, I know that I can resort to those tools to create a better answer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal/255020

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The best answers on Stack Overflow are those that, first and foremost, answer the question to solve the asker's problem. This includes a brief explanation, as well as a code example. If you've done that, and the problem is solved, then you've met the standard. Nice work!

However, Stack Overflow exists not just to tell but also to *teach*. Therefore, as a professional in your field (or an enthusiast with a lot of skill and knowledge), it's possible you may have noticed a pattern that may lead this asker down the very same path to needing more help on the same *type* of problem in the future.

If you can provide more value by teaching the asker how to fish (a.k.a offering some tips on how to solve similar problems yourself) then you are just the type of user I enjoy working with the most on Stack Exchange! As long as the additional information doesn't overwhelm the meat and potatoes of the actual answer, I wouldn't remove it, as it is valuable.

As for the "snark", now that you mention it, I do see a little bit of that, but not enough to where it raises any red flags.  If you wish to, consider editing it to use slightly different wordings. Take the approach of someone helping a friend. For instance, consider the following edit:

> As an aside, these types of problems are something you will run into again. Here are some things you can do to help identify these problems yourself in the future:
>
> - Place a console.log inside of your equalCheck. This shows you the function is only called once.
> - Place a console log everywhere you set a value. This shows you whether you are comparing the wrong value.
> - Learn what the different types of highlighting means inside JSFiddle and your code editor, as this will show you if the code sections are in the wrong categories.

The trick is to use active rather than passive voice. This looks less condescending and is more reminiscent of the technical language we oftentimes see in documentation. Please feel free to use any of that and put it in your own words.

Perhaps the best value of being a Stack Overflow answerer is the improvements we gain in terms of our own written communications. Hone this skill, and doors will open for you, and people will follow and look up to you as a leader. Hope this helps!

Comment: Honestly, I like his current wording better.  I find your proposed wording rambling and a little paternalistic.

Comment: Yeah, being too "friendly" results in advice not being followed. Making it slightly passively snarky underlines the importance of the tips, and suggests that the OP should already be following that advice (which is, of course, true) ("What do you mean you didn't debug this? Are you mad?!" "Oh, okay, sorry..." They won't make that mistake again). Subconsciously, then, they will feel a sense of urgency to "catch up" to the rest of us and actually learn it.

Comment: “Stack Overflow exists not just to tell but also to teach” – *yes*. Many users not only forget this but outright (and explicitly) *refuse* to recognise this. It’s very infuriating.

Comment: It seems that it's all about finding the right balance between "Please, here is the solution for you my friend" and "I, the mighty wizard from the ivory tower so high you're not worthy even looking up, point my finger down at thou and graciously reveal my wisdom to your primitive eyes".

Comment: This answer makes me like SO again. After [Are we elitist? Is it wrong?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262446/are-we-being-elitist-is-there-something-wrong-with-that) where the consensus was that teaching someone something basic like debugging is way beneath SO I am happy to see that there are different opinions.

Comment: @tmyklebu that is very subjective and most probably culture dependent. I do not find his wording paternalistic for instance. However, in all honesty, if the wording is not offensive and as long as the information is there, I would not mind either way...

Comment: @BartoszKP: That's a pretty good way to put it.  I think that being brief and direct---not rambling, fake, and "positive" but also not actively snarky---is the way to do that.

Comment: @nico: I grew up in a culture (North America) where rambling, smarmy, paternalistic crap is considered "polite."  I don't think this brand of "politeness" is useful even for people steeped in it from birth.

Comment: @tmyklebu, just to clarify, this is just my own personal style, and I have to say it yields very positive results for me. However, you should definitely use whatever style works for you. The main takeaway is this:  If you're consistently running into people who you've made angry, upset, or embarrassed because of how you've worded something, you might want to consider experimenting with some different words or phrases, so the heart of your message isn't diluted. It's not just about being nice, it's also improving your own technical writing skills for a larger audience. Hope this helps clarify.