# The good in bad questions

Tags: discussion, new-users, bad-questions

I guess this essentially boils down to 'quality questions vs helping noobs' or 'does SO suffer from elitism'. (And turned out not to really be a question)

The SO '[mission statement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/)' (if you would call it that) said "Better programming is our goal". But where does better programming come from, good documentation of problems and solutions, or teaching people to program? The answer is obviously both, but does SO do both? I personally don't think so.

I worry that focusing (entirely) on good questions will be bad for the site long term. As new people start programming they will end up searching (Google usually leads to SO) and asking often bad, duplicated, simple questions due to lack of simple knowledge, and this gets annoying.
However this doesn't stop once people grasp the basics of program, the learning curve continues through OO programming, good design and structure, testing, frameworks and other new techniques that will be developed in the future. It takes a long time to become a competent programmer, and even longer to become 'good'.

I have two examples from the first two questions I asked which I still have. They were closed for being too broad or unclear after getting answers which I accepted. Questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060805/controlling-c-sharp-form-elements-properties) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885810/structure-code-to-access-multiple-objects-c).

I can understand that they are not great questions (I also state this in the questions themselves), and I don't mind that they were down voted, if you don't like a question that is your prerogative (although comments explaining why they are bad help). However, while some people felt they were bad questions, in each case they were answered and those answers benefited my knowledge hugely. Namely they got me to look into reflection and design patterns.

I have always had trouble picking up new programming concepts until I could see a clear example where it helped me with a problem that I was currently working on. It took me quite a long time to see the benefit of OO programming, now I don't think I could write anything without OO. Basically the whole you can have a class called animal, then inherit from it to make different types of animal... etc, didn't really help me get OO. I got OO once I got to a problem and someone actually showed me how re-structuring my code into classes would make everything much easier.

Now imagine if they were closed before someone could answer, for the first question I would have given up on that particular feature, for the second one I would have written some horrible hard to read code that did the job, but badly. Yes they were too vague for some people to understand, or people simply didn't want to spend long deciphering my bad question, but someone did and I'm really glad they did.

So can we achieve "Better programming" without explaining to people who ask those bad questions, due to their lack of knowledge, that their problem isn't purely "you need this code" but "you need this code plus this knowledge to write your program properly".

If we don't accommodate learning those new users won't stop asking bad questions, they will just ask them somewhere else, and SO will slowly die. But those of us who are willing to answer the bad question just might help someone become a better programmer, and they might stick around and start asking (and answering) better questions.

Comment: *"However this doesn't stop once people grasp the basics of program[ming]"* I'd argue that part of the basics of programming is learning how to search, and how to ask a good question. It's possible to ask a good question about something you don't know much about.

Comment: *"If we don't accommodate learning those new users won't stop asking bad questions, they will just ask them somewhere else,"* --- We want users to ask bad questions somewhere else....that's the point.

Comment: adding to @Undo's: not only searching, also how to divide a big task on smaller ones

Comment: Easy, beginner questions can be on topic for stack overflow, but they still have to follow all of our quality standards. I don't see what you're getting at here.

Comment: I don't see the questions you asked as being unclear or too broad, but maybe that's my lack of understanding of the topic at hand.

Comment: I don't know where everyone keeps getting these ideas like "beginners can't ask questions here" and "questions are downvoted for being easy." My _very first_ question was a beginner one. It's my highest voted question thus far. Like Kevin B said, it's not a matter of how easy the question is but of how well it's asked. Ask a question in an unclear way, or without showing what you've tried, expect downvotes. If it's unclear, expect close votes. Simple as that. These questions aren't bad because they're beginner questions- They're bad because they don't follow the standard of quality.

Comment: What I was trying to get at is that sometimes people don't possess the understanding of a topic to ask a well formed question. Answering it will still help them and hopefully make them a better programmer in the process.

Also I didn't say "beginners can't ask questions here" what I'm getting at is that closing their question isn't going to make them ask better questions in the future if they don't learn anything.

Comment: And my point is not understanding a topic doesn't make your question badly formed. I didn't understand how to test a string against a regex- I still asked a good, well-received question. How did I ever manage that apparently difficult feat? I read the [ask] page. I showed what I tried, and explained why it wasn't working and what I expected. That's what's wrong with these questions- Most of them don't give us the information needed to make the post useful to future users. Or, it's already been asked 100 times before, and the user didn't search. It's not the user not understanding the topic.

Comment: _"what I'm getting at is that closing their question isn't going to make them ask better questions in the future if they don't learn anything."_ Closing their questions gives them a nice little blurb about what exactly is wrong with their question. We tell them _how they can fix the question_ and most of the time, they ignore that blurb. They won't ask better questions if they don't learn anything, you're right. But what they aren't learning that would help them is how to read what we're telling them they need to do to fix the question. No amount of programming knowledge will fix this.

Comment: And concerning _'Also I didn't say "beginners can't ask questions here"'_ in a way you did. By saying the user doesn't have the knowledge of the topic they are asking about, you are implicitly saying they are a beginner in that topic. This essentially boils it down to "beginners are getting their questions closed not answered" which is pretty much "beginners can't ask questions here." (Not as in "They are prohibited" but as in "the community is preventing this by closing their questions.)

Comment: Not knowing how to test a string against a regex means you don't know how to do something, you still understand what needs to be done. Some users ask the bad question 'x doesn't work' or 'how do I do x' because they lack some understanding of a programming concept.

Comment: _'x doesn't work'_ is different from _'how do I do x'_ in that it's automatically assumed you tried something for 'x' to find out it doesn't work. When the former questions get shut down, it's because they don't show what they tried (often times) and therefore we can't help them. In the latter example, it's often times the case that the user has tried _nothing at all_ and just wants us to tell them how they can do it so they can copy/paste the code over. If they _aren't_ this kind of user, they typically respond well to requests to clarify their question and show what they've tried.

Comment: The reason I included two of my own questions is because they were actually answered and they helped me learn not just how to do the thing I asked, but also showed me I should be learning specific techniques which could be applied to similar future problems. Closing questions sometimes leads to questions not being answered that could be.

Comment: @Mike159 so, this may sound rude, but it isn't. I'm just exaggerating my point to make it more blatant. Stack gets 8K questions A DAY (IIRC). Let's say 20% are terrible questions like the ones you describe. That's 1,6K questions A DAY that need that kind of hand-holding. Can we get your cellphone number and personal email so that you can answer each individually? The problem here is THAT: scalability. with the scale stack currently works at, we can't simply give THAT much help to every new user on every new topic. Unfortunate, yes. Instead Stack tries to build a repo of good knowledge.

Comment: Since there is not enough experts to give all this free tutorial like knowledge, Stack decided to build a long lasting repository of knowledge. This way, programming becomes better, because people who care about researching a bit CAN get their solution. I often say on meta that the main issue to me seems that people think we're a helpdesk. Why? Our answers are TOO popular on google. So whenever you search "how does X work". if X is programming, you WILL see Stack in there. So you think Stack can answer ANYTHING about coding. Then you create an account, ask a bad question, and expect an answer

Comment: @Patrice that is a very good point, I didn't have numbers on questions/day but having to sort though that many bad questions would certainly detract from answering the good questions. I wasn't saying bad questions shouldn't be closed, but for example was my question marked unclear really unclear if someone was able to provide a good answer? (Obviously people though so, fortunately someone was able to understand what I was getting at)

Comment: @Mike159 it may still be unclear. Maybe the one answer you got made an assumption? Maybe he understood something in your question that 5 other members couldn't see? The fact ONE guy understands doesn't mean it's clear. If it's unclear, chances are it won't pop in a lot of Google searches. Stack is all about that: the value to the NEXT guy with the same issue. To help that, we like to have good, clear questions to help people who search for similar issues get their answer (admittedly I've not looked into your question, so I may just be talking sh*t right now :P)

Comment: @Patrice No, I expect that is probably what happened. What I was getting at was had the question been closed before someone answered, maybe I would have not looked into design patterns when I did and asked several more poorly formed questions that boiled down to me not structuring something properly. But as you pointed out SO isn't about hand holding and people don't often have time for it.

Comment: @Mike159 most definitely. But when your question gets closed as unclear, it explains what you should do to get it reopened. Doing so means you edit it, which bumps it to the top of the new questions. So if you edit it into a clearer shape, you will likely get the same answer. A big problem that happens is also new users don't want to learn the system so think closed = you're done, when closed = please correct what's lacking, then we'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Patrice Yeah, I think the problem is (epically for people that have already tried searching for answers) that having a question closed/down voted might put them off. I guess it comes down to how well they understand the working of SO

Comment: *closing their question isn't going to make them ask better questions in the future if they don't learn anything.* yes it does it clears out the noise for everyone until that person gets the message and improves or gets question banned. I would argue that is when they are forced to **learn something**, improve or move on to somewhere else.

Comment: @Mike159 see that's a point I give you in full : Stack looks very unfriendly if you don't know how it works. My take on this: new users have a LOT of resources about how the system works. From meta, to the help center, the information is THERE. We even ask new users to read the tour. Each closing message links into help center. New users HAVE the resources. If they don't use it.... what can we do?

Comment: @Mike159 as an aside, consider that most new users, when faced with this situation, don't come to meta with an open mind like you do. Most of the time, we get called "police", "nazis", "idiots who downvote what they can't understand". I've also recently seen a user LITERALLY say "I don't care about your quality rules, just answer my questions". This is what normally happens when new users aren't clear on Stack's way. You can guess why veterans don't want to hand-hold if that's the expected reaction

Comment: @Patrice - the % of crap is more like 80% or more in some of the tags, those that are taught in university mainly and the entitlement attitude in those tags is off the charts as well.

Comment: If you treat a garage technician, doctor, lawyer or accountant the same way SO contributors are treated, you end up with a $xxxx extra on your bill.  Nobody would just dump their car at a garage with a note 'Fix my car, i need it tomorrow', so why are skilled and experienced engineers on SO different?... oh yeah, we don't get paid, so it's fine to slag us off and treat us as lowlifes.

Comment: @Mike159 - if someone craps on your front porch and wipes their hands on your door even though there is a sign that says where actually take a dump and find tp, why should you care if they whine *(that having a question closed/down voted might put them off)* about getting hit by the water hose as you clean up the mess they made? *I guess it comes down to how well they understand the working of SO*, no **It comes down to how selfish they are. And how much they care about looking like selfish entitled brats.** The anonymous usernames do not help the latter.

Comment: this question is just [apologetics](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apologetics) and mainly to blame for the entitlement attitude that prevails the "summer of love" generation of SO users.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson yes, it's  a social thing in general.  Some posters are little more than deadbeat thugs with a computer and, if they were to carry that 'tude into a downtown bar on Friday night, would be very lucky to only end up in hospital.

Comment: @MartinJames "Some posters are little more than deadbeat thugs with a computer". Well that seems a little harsh. I didn't intend for my question to come across as "I don't like my bad question being closed I think I'm right", I marked it as discussion so people could discuss if I had any valid points. I'll admit I was bias from my own experience but I am open to having my mind changed, and some people have given me very good explanations of why I was wrong

Comment: @Mike159 sadly, it happens.  You don't immediately rush to answer the URGENT homework they've had for a week, (or, in some cases, homework they are being paid so do my someone else), they get extremely offensive:(

Comment: @Mike159 I think I see where our earlier disconnect was- Had I realized that you didn't see the scale issue, I could have brought that up. Glad to see, however, that some understanding is starting to go on (not just from your side, but also more people being able to understand what _you_ mean and where you're coming from.) By the way, you mention Stack Overflow being elitest in your post- You might get something out of reading [another meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262446/) on that very subject.  (And thanks for actually being constructive in comments. It's a nice change of pace.)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson what is the Summer of Love generation of SO users?

Comment: the ones that can't google for information on their own and want to be spoon fed said information ... did you even **consider** googling *summer of love stackoverflow*?

Comment: @MartinJames I can understand why that type of question could get annoying. I personally haven't seen it before on SO (although I have on other forums)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Touché

Comment: @Kendra I will take a look. I don't think elitest was the right word. What I meant is that the people with the rep to close questions are probably fairly experience programmers. I know from first hand experience (both teaching and learning) the sometimes experts can find it hard to understand why someone doesn't understand something that to them is simple.

Comment: The experts find it hard to understand why posters don't provide as much detail as they can with their questions.  Eventually, it sinks in that many of  the posters are not just beginners, seeking to learn, who have gone astray and somehow missed all the site rules, tour etc.  They are malicious, medancious deadbeats whose only aim it to get as much work done for them for free as possible whilst doing absolutely none themseves, either because they wish to pass their own course with no effort or are taking cash to answer homework questions for others and so cannot provide extra details.

Comment: Exhibit A, homework vampire: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292641/preemptive-vs-non-preemptive-multitasking-in-parallelism-timing-and-performance

Comment: Exhibit B, do homework that I sell to others, (10k+): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975019/i-need-complexity-of-the-codes-written-below

Comment: Exhibit C, 'I scanned my homework, come on, get it done!': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144131/c-program-running-in-linux-add-and-delete

Comment: Exhibit D: 'irrelevant comments,  too arrogant to even read the question properly, you don't understand,  you don't have solutions' - we asked for code, silly us, 10K+:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665338/bad-file-descriptor-even-though-file-descriptor-is-valid

Comment: Exhibit E, 'Do all muy work.  If you can not help, then do not bother me', 10k+: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288519/convert-this-code-from-c-to-objective-c

Comment: Exhibit F, 'I didn't actually compile the code myself, just typed it in Notepad.  Now fix all the syntax etc. errors for me', 10k+: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621800/can-someone-look-over-my-small-algorithm-that-sorts-gems-by-their-color

Comment: So you're saying SO should remove its quality standards so that it can help you more, at the expense of everyone else in the world, and yet *we're* the entitled ones?  Sorry, you have that backward.  If you want to have a site with no quality standards, there are many thousands of them out there.  Almost no sites besides SO have quality standards.  Of course, those sites are flooded with low quality content, and don't have many active, smart, knowledgeable programmers answering questions there.  That's not a coincidence.  Smart people come to SO precisely because it has quality standards.

Comment: Exhibit G, so bad it defies description, 10l+: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563994/can-anyone-convert-the-string-logic-of-following-program-to-be-converted-in-java

Comment: Anyway, before I run out of letters, like a Windows file system gone mad, I'm gonna open a bottle of Stoli.  Looking back over those questions has resulted in a massive thirst.

Comment: but..I just have to put this one in.   Exhibit H: ' i searched a lot on the internet, but i couldn't find any tips/hints': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299410/robertsons-algorithm

Answer (score 13):

A "good" question is not the same thing as an "advanced topic" question.

An "easy" or "newbie" question is not the same as a bad question.

In my experience (which is admittedly mostly as a lurker), questions get downvoted for:

- Being unclear
- Not giving any indication that the asker put any real effort into solving it before asking
- Being a duplicate of a very commonly asked question (which falls into the same category as the previous item)
- Not showing what they tried

I don't see many (if any) instances of questions getting negative scores without meeting at least one of those criteria.

I've asked a couple of relatively basic questions over time.  The worst thing that happened?  I didn't get any upvotes.  In only one case did I not get an answer at all, but I still received useful feedback in comments.

Note that even in your example questions, you received what appears to be useful feedback, pointing you towards improving your skills.

Overall, I disagree with your stated concerns, and feel that discouraging bad questions (as opposed to "simple" questions) should continue.  Certainly the site is not in danger of slowly dying, as this treatment of bad questions is far from a new thing.