# How do I react to someone with a higher rep deleting a question that a lower rep user is 100% confident of the answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Let's say an experienced user (+10K rep, a decent history of Q&As, thus an "expert"), makes a question that involves the newest development trend in which he is clearly new on but the issue is really about something else and someone with a clearly lower reputation, a "beginner" (you guessed it, me!) answers it. He responds in a comment that the pattern he was using was "acceptable" and that my answer didn't help. After stating that I had the same problem and my solution works, he says that my answer has nothing to do with the problem, which by the way was **a method not being resolved**, and after a few minutes the question is deleted. His profile states that he "hopes to be able to contribute to the community in a positive light" and the question even stated "any help will be appreciated". I'm sure I'm not the first one to experience such a thing, and I don't blame anyone with a high rep looking down, but a further research on his questions only makes me think that he only welcomes help from high rep users and disregards it from low rep users. That's discrimination to me, and I can't find a mechanism to deal with it here yet.

Here is the question: let's say the circumstance is real and two hypothetical users fall in these actions. Should we just move on and answer more questions?

Comment: Why are you so certain that the deletion of the question has anything to do with your answer?

Comment: Because like I said I experienced the same problem once, and I am 100% convinced that it solved the question

Comment: @Chisko how do you know you didn't misread the question and the problem.

Comment: I didn't. I had the exact same problem once. I read the question several times.

Comment: Should I edit the question and state that it had about 30 mins without any answers until this happened? And also that this is not the first time that it had happened to me, but the time that I'm 100% convinced of my words and actions?

Comment: He isnt violating any community rules based on your description. Go to your deleted posts and get us a link so we can take a look. Based on the conjecture stated in your question, I'd say the correct action is to move on and answer some more questions.

Comment: Sure, this is the id: 40877571

Comment: Forgive me, but we only have your word on this. You haven't provided any links or images to support your position. The way you have written this question is very one-sided, and is bordering on a "evil" high rep user taking advantage of a low rep user rant. I'm not saying your concern is unfounded, but my meta experience shows many posts if this nature based only on first person narratives have significant bias.

Comment: I just provided the question ID. And yes, I understand your point. I just would prefer some guideance and/or clarification instead of massive dismission :)

Comment: Remotely related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262446/5647260

Comment: I mean, is this a considered problem in the community? Are we positive that everyone acts in good will and never trying to hide when we make a mistake when we should know better, and also probably trying to take things personally?

Comment: is [this the question you are talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877571/cannot-resolve-getviewmodel-method)? if not then provide a link because i got that link by using only your id

Comment: And for everyone downvoting the question and voting the comments where I'm being asked, let's say I am right, don't question, this is a real possibility.

Comment: @Memor-X yes, that is the question. It's deleted. It says so in the question.

Comment: @Chisko and 10k users can still see it if they go to the link

Comment: [Your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877571/cannot-resolve-getviewmodel-method/40878062#40878062) addressed a way to resolve a NullPointerError, but OP specifically said an NPE was not part of OP's problem. As OP wrote in a comment on your answer, "I'm not getting a NPE. The methods aren't resolving. I'm sure that you CAN do this, but it's not needed and it isn't solving the problem. What you are suggesting has nothing to do with my issue." Besides, the OP is entitled to delete the question if it doesn't have any positive-scoring answers, which that one did not.

Comment: no, my answer did not had to do anything with NPE. I just used the term because to me it's similar to a method not being able to be resolved.

Comment: I mean: "you don't have to create a view in `onCreateViewHolder()`"... really?

Comment: *this is not the first time that it had happened to me* - By the same user? If it's the same user, I'd avoid that person's questions. In general though, the question ban algorithm is what's supposed to discourage question deletion. The only way to guarantee that someone won't delete right after you answer is to wait until there's already a positively scored answer.

Comment: @BSMP no, not by the same user. What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Different users...accept that question deletion happens and move on. There really isn't anything you can do about it. As for, *makes me think that he only welcomes help from high rep users and disregards it from low rep users*, all a question asker can do is accept and up vote once. Write answers that will help the whole community and they'll up vote your answers. We often say "down votes aren't personal" but the same applies to lack of up votes/check marks.

Comment: I'm welcome and open to hear when I'm wrong and taking SO votes or downvotes as personal would be the biggest energy leak your mind can possibly have. Anyway, my question was about a matter that I think is not considered and thought I could contribute to something. Thank you

Comment: @BSMP and also how do you know that answer was not helpful for the comminuty. I think it was. It was a mistake made by someone who clearly shouldn't have done it, his reputation backs him. I made it myself before, there's two. I think it was useful for the community

Comment: I read most of this and still don't understand what gave you the idea that reputation has anything to do with it. If you feel inferior because you have fewer random Internet points than someone else, then *don't.* Because you *aren't.* This same thing has happened to me a couple times, and almost always did I have more points than the person whose question I was answering. You think anybody cared?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm not sure what gave anyone the impression that I feel inferior, because I don't. Read it again, because I said: "I think (the situation) is not considered and thought I could contribute to something."

Comment: Thank you @gnat. First useful words anyone said. And please note the differences between how this was commented and answered and my question. What does one need to do to be not looked down on here?

Comment: I never said your answer wasn't useful, I can't even see your answer. I said if the answer is useful, someone other than the OP will vote it up. You were upset that the OP didn't accept your answer so I'm pointing out that you can get votes from other people too. That is not an attack on you or your post.

Comment: @BSMP you implied it was not. And no, I was not upset because he didn't accept my answer, I was because I know it was correct and he was not humble enough to take a look and disregarded my knowledge. What I did would have been a merit if this was a software company, instead I got downvoted and judged. But nevermind. You guys are just NEVER WRONG.

Comment: @Chisko "And please note the differences between how [the duplicate question] was commented and answered and my question." -- Note that the duplicate question didn't involve psychological speculation about the motives of the asker, which probably helps explaining how differently it was received.

Comment: `What does one need to do to be not looked down on here?` I'd say don't accuse other people of acting in bad faith based on no evidence.  That's not surprisingly very important.  Also, when people say that you're wrong, it might be a good idea to consider that as a possibility instead of taking a defensive stance.

Answer (score 14):

The comments on your answer were perfectly polite and constructive. I don't see any reason to suspect "discrimination" or anything of that nature. You do not know *why* the asker deleted the question. Perhaps they figured out the root cause of the problem was somewhere else entirely, and the question was misleading or too out-of-the-way for any actual answer to be useful. Perhaps they couldn't be bothered formulating their own answer (which would be preferable, but is up to the asker).

Accept the fact that your answer may or may not have been the solution, and that the asker may have removed the question for reasons completely unrelated to you.

Comment: Anyone with a basic understanding of Android's adapters and databinding would tell you differently. You are still disregarding what the question is about.

Comment: This is absolutely not about the technical specifics of the specific question and answer. The OP simply did not see how your answer applied to their question, **rightly or wrongly.** I cannot and will not judge that. You offered an answer, they didn't take it, it simply didn't work out. Nobody was being unreasonable at any point. Why the OP then removed the question is yet another completely different topic. I'm telling you there's no point in getting hung up about it. Which is what your question was about, which is what I answered.

Comment: Wait, this situation sounds familiar. Am I falling for a troll? Dang! :-D

Comment: I suppose this is fun for you. Good. You are nothing but reinforcing the basis of the situation.